# Error "SELECT is not valid input at this position for this server version, expecting : '(' WITH" in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I am trying to retrieve the SSNs of employees who work for all projects that John Smith works on.  Specifically, I'm supposed to show the functionality of the division operation.  I have a few examples from a textbook using nested functions, but I continuously receive the error "SELECT is not valid input at this position".

I've tried the suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53471882/mysql-workbench-reports-is-not-valid-at-this-position-for-this-server-version) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53773826/mysql-workbench-error-while-trying-nested-query).  The error pops up as soon as I create a nested function... Individually, the statements execute without issue.

I followed various examples in my textbook, and even those give the same error.

```sql
# This works by itself
# smith proj nums
(SELECT Pno
FROM WORKS_ON
WHERE Essn =    # smith ssn
                (SELECT ssn 
                FROM employee 
                WHERE Fname="John" AND Lname="Smith"));

# This also works by itself:
# employee SSNs and projs
(SELECT Essn,Pno
from WORKS_ON);

# When nested, I get the error:
SELECT ssn
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT Essn,Pno
                 FROM WORKS_ON
                 EXCEPT(SELECT Pno
                        FROM WORKS_ON
                        WHERE Essn = (SELECT ssn 
                                FROM employee 
                                WHERE Fname="John" AND Lname="Smith")));
```

Comment: `EXCEPT` keyword is not supported in MySQL. It's a Transact-SQL keyword, supported in Microsoft SQL Server.  (The specification "employees who work for all projects that John Smith works on" could be interpreted in a couple of different ways.)

Comment: I'm a complete noob at SQL, so I did not know that.  I've found that NOT IN can be used equivalently.  I'll give that a go..

Comment: Standard SQL permits "levels" of compliance, so each company who makes an SQL database product may implement the features they want to support, and still call it SQL. You need to study the documentation for the exact brand and version you're using to be sure about the syntax it supports.